# Unable to get whole user details in XML document

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

First here i show you my XML document, and then i wanted to read those values using C# code but here i received a Username usr & Password pwd Only.

```
<Users>
  <user>
    <username>abc</username>
    <password>def</password>
  </user>
  <user>
    <username>usr</username>
    <password>pwd</password>
  </user>
</Users>
```

Java Code:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(Application.StartupPath+"\\load.xml");

        foreach (XmlNode node in xDoc.SelectNodes("//Users/user"))
        {
            string Username = node.FirstChild.InnerText;
            string Password = node.LastChild.InnerText;


          // Some coding goes here
        }

    }
```

I need both users details. Whats wrong in my XPath query ?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Why do you think you aren't getting both users details?

Comment: Your XML isn't valid.

Comment: @Romoku: It's just missing a closing `Users` tag. I don't think that's the problem here.

Comment: @Romoku It's there.my paste problem here.

Comment: Please state what result you're getting, and what result you expected. As Daniel said, how do you know you're only getting one user's details?

Comment: @LarsH I debug this program & once it debugging,Loop runs only 1 time and get 1 value & exit from it.(it shows item count also only 1 )

Answer (score 1):

Because each time you set `Username` and `Password` you're creating new variables that fall immediately out of scope (depending on what `Some coding goes here` actually is/does). Create some higher level scoped variables and store the values there, but even then you would be overwriting the same values each time, hence ending up with the last credential set only - so, use a collection to store them in.

```
var credentials = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

credentials.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
  node.FirstChild.InnerText, node.LastChild.InnerText)
);
```

If you're doing something with the queried values *within* the loop then I could stand corrected, but it's not clear *where* you expect to use these (e.g. reusing tightly-scoped variables might be perfectly valid if such is the case).

Comment: Here i tried this.It also read second values. username - abc & password - def not reading

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var xDoc= XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath+"\\load.xml");

var userlist = xDoc.Descendants("users").Descendants("user")
            .Select(u => new {
                                Username = u.Element("username").Value,
                                Password = u.Element("password").Value
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: It shows "System.XML.XMLNodeList" does not contain a definition for 'Select' and No extension method for 'Select' .... etc.

Comment: @Sonic99 you need to use `XDocument`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to extract your elements.

Classes:

```
[XmlRoot("users")]
public class UserResult
{
    [XmlElement("user")]
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [XmlElement("username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var xml = @"<users>
<user>
<username>abc</username>
<password>def</password>
</user>
<user>
<username>usr</username>
<password>pwd</password>
</user>
</users>";

var document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(xml);

UserResult result;
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UserResult));

using(var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    result = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<UserDetails> GetUserDetails()
        {
            XDocument xDOC = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath+"\\load.xml");
            List<UserDetails> retVal = (from xele in xDOC.Descendants("User")
                                        select new UserDetails
                                        {
                                            UserName = xele.Element("username").Value,
                                            Password = xele.Element("password").Value
                                        }).ToList<UserDetails>();

            return retVal;

        }
    }

    public class UserDetails
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```